# Inline Crontab Commands?

Tags: cron, command

Is the following crontab possible?

```
0 4 * * * /sbin/sudo shutdown -r now
```

I want to run a single command, sudo shutdown -r now, from a crontab without having to put it in a bash script.

Comment: Cron won't give sudo a tty, and could ask for a password, so be sure to account for that

Comment: put it in the root user's cron table and you won't need `sudo`, in which case it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, `sudo` will be useless in a `crontab`.  The `cron` program runs the commands in a restricted environment (most notably a very limited `PATH` and no controlling tty).  While you could probably get this to work by installing severe security holes, the right way to achieve what you probably want is to put the command `shutdown -r now` in root's `crontab`.

You obviously don't expect to ever be doing anything at 4 AM on the machine in question, but as a precaution for a rare case when you are, you might want to give the `shutdown` command some time and a real message.  Then, if you are there, you can either cleanup or abort the shutdown in the interval.  It's a real pity to have something like this kick in just after you've spent half an hour editing something and have no chance to save it.

Answer (score 1):

Ekhm yes, read the fabulous manuals?

From `man crontab`

```
   The  sixth  field  of  a line in a crontab entry is a string that shall be executed by sh at the specified times. A
   <percent-sign> character in this field shall be translated to a <newline>.  Any character preceded by a <backslash>
   (including the '%') shall cause that character to be treated literally. Only the first line (up to a '%' or end-of-
   line) of the command field shall be executed by the command interpreter. The other lines shall be made available to
   the command as standard input.
```

Although I would be careful with the PATH, I'd include the full path to `/usr/bin/shutdown` (it may require a change to `/etc/sudoers`).